# Let $a_n$ be bounded so that for every $n>=2$ the following occurs: $a_{n+1} - a_n > a_n - a_{n-1}$. Prove that $a_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus

Given that $a_n$ is bounded, all that's left to do is to show that it is monotonic, then we can conclude that it converges.
So here's what I figured out so far, let $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$, then $b_n$ is monotonic, but I'm not quite sure how that can help me prove that $a_n$ is also monotonic, not sure If these 2 are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(a_n)$ is bounded above by $M$ then for all $m > n \ge 1$
$$
 M \ge a_m = a_n + \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k) \ge a_n + (m-n) (a_{n+1}-a_n) \\
\implies a_{n+1}-a_n \le \frac{M - a_n}{m-n} \, .
$$
Taking the limit $m \to \infty$ it follows that $ a_{n+1}-a_n \le 0$, so that the sequence is decreasing.

In other words: A *convex* sequence which is bounded above is necessarily decreasing.

Comment: I don't fully understand the part where you defined $a_m$, do you mind explaining it further? Thanks

Comment: @user1780131: I just wrote $a_m = a_n + (a_{n+1}-a_n) + (a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}) + \ldots + (a_m - a_{m-1})$. Or, in your notation, $a_m = a_n + b_n + b_{n+1}+ \ldots + b_{m-1} \ge a_n \ge (m-n)b_n$.

Comment: It's clear now thanks :)